# What does "しっかり" mean when used "叩いて"?

Tags: translation

Playing a japanese game online at the moment and some guy told me this as an advice.

> 奴さんしっかり叩いて次から標的を儂たちだけに絞ってもらおうじゃないか

I don't really understand the 1st part of the sentence here.

The part which I can roughly understand is "標的を儂たちだけに絞ってもらおうじゃないか" , which I translate as "we turn ourselves into a target". Please tell me if that's wrong.

So the main question is what "奴さんしっかり叩いて" means. I've only heard it use when referring to sort of labour that can be done "properly" or "surely".

What does it mean when used with "叩いて"?

Answer (score 2):

奴{やっこ}さんしっかり叩いて： firmly beat him

次から： from the next time (and so on)

標的を儂たちだけに絞って： narrow the targets into only us

もらおう： let's let him

じゃないか： Why not?

"Let's beat him firmly and let him aim only us from the next time, don't we?"